# Uncaught Exception: Warning: fwrite(): SSL operation failed with code 1

Tags: magento2, laminas

Magento 2.4 is using this module facinf error while sending success email:

`error:1420C0CF:SSL routines:ssl_write_internal:protocol is shutdown in /app/vendor/laminas/laminas-mail/src/Protocol/AbstractProtocol.php on line 253 in /app/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61`

Stack trace:

```
#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler-&gt;handler()
#1 /app/vendor/laminas/laminas-mail/src/Protocol/AbstractProtocol.php(253): fwrite()
#2 /app/vendor/laminas/laminas-mail/src/Protocol/Smtp.php(454): Laminas\Mail\Protocol\AbstractProtocol-&gt;_send()
#3 /app/vendor/laminas/laminas-mail/src/Protocol/Smtp.php(493): Laminas\Mail\Protocol\Smtp-&gt;quit()
#4 /op in <b>/app/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php</b> on line <b>61</b><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is already answered I hope it will help you.
You can check the below link-

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59874613/fwrite-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-openssl-error-messageserror1420c0c

Answer (score 0):

I resolve from following link:

https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-smtp/issues/293